# iOS app that can retrieve database query output from web service?

Tags: c#, ios, xml, web-services

I am not a developer, so explain it like I am five. Does not have to go into detail, just point me in a direction I will spend the next 2-4 weeks of free time (hopefully) trying to work through it.

Our retail system runs on a UniData database, commands include "listuser" "kill __" etc.

We have a web service that can be seen externally.

I want to make a rudimentary iOS app that can "listuser" and see output of connected users, read through the list, and type in a user name then send the "kill ___" command back through the web service to our server.

I created a batch file with the listuser command, then wrote some C# code that will pass output into XML document, I just want to be able to trigger this & load the XML from my iOS app.

```
public XmlDocument ListUnidataUser(string VisibleStores)
    {
         Process p = new Process();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\server\c$\ud\listuser.bat";
        p.Start();
            // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
            // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
            // p.WaitForExit();
            // Read the output stream first and then wait.
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(output);
        p.WaitForExit();
        return xml;            
    }
```

After this, I have no idea what I am doing. This goes in our web service, which can see these local servers, then the web service holds that XML. How do I make a connection from an external app?

If it is easier to learn, I wouldn't mind trying first to make C# code that can be run externally to grab this, and using a service like Xamarin to compile it for iOS, but I am curious to feel my way around Xcode as well.

Please don't flame me, I can hear the jimmies rustling by my approach to coding this.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to learn something new, and I for one think that the iOS framework really has a good structure - so good luck.

As for your problem:

If possible for you, don't use XML as data protocol - mobile frameworks are much better at interpreting `JSON`, it's even integrated in the language itself (`NSJSONSerializer` for example) or you get good libraries for it.

For contacting your Webservice, have a look at `NSURLSession` or, if you prefer a library with some more functionality, [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (or [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) if you're using Swift.

In general, look at some tutorials on the [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com) website - they are great for learning about developing for iOS, eg the one on [AlamoFire](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial).